# How to retrieve natural features of a certain GeoLocation with OSM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

In a node web-application I need to find out, what the natural features of the location of the user are.
I know the longitude and latitude of a user and I found out, that the tag **natural** holds information like water, rock or grass which would suffice for my applicatiton. As I understand, not every single GeoLocation holds this kind of information.

My research so far got me to consider the OSM-APIs **Overpass API** and the **XAPI** (whereas Xappy.JS which I would prefer using for my nodejs-project, seems to be down currently) as both their key-goals are, to provide information rather than edit geo-information.

I am still not sure, if I can simply get natural features, only providing a Geo-Location, or maybe a rectangle, without having to download surrounding map-data beforehand.

My question is: Which API would you recommend to use for this? Maybe you can give any recommendations on what specific functionality I need to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving natural features from OSM via the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) is surely a possible solution. See this [example query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/36F) using [overpass turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) (which is just a nice web-frontend for the Overpass API).

Note that the Overpass API supports [XML and JSON](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Choose_file_format) and that overpass turbo adds [some more file formats](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo#Exporting_Results).

Also do note that there might be other interesting keys apart from the [natural key](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3anatural). Take a look at the [map features](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) which roughly correspond to the most commonly used [tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). Additionally, there is [taginfo](http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/) where you can find even more tags.

Comment: Just as addition, the general topic of this task is "reverse geocoding" and e.g. [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) can be use to do so. But AFAIK it doesn't hold natural/landuse information right now.